# How to enable HTTPS for Elastic Beanstalk url

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have enabled HTTPS for my custom domain name (haydenclay.page), but I also need the Beanstalk url (app-name.elasticbeanstalk.com) to run through HTTPS as well.

HTTPS does not work currently, because the cert name matches my custom domain name, yielding: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I need HTTPS because I make API requests, and going from HTTPS to HTTP throws a mixed content error. How can I enabled HTTPS on the beanstalk url?

I have already tried making an alias [image: in the console like so]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sadly you **can't enable** https directly for `app-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` domain. This is because this domain is controlled by AWS. You can only register SSL certificates for **domains that you control**.

If you want to server your content from EB over ssl, you have generally **three options**.

1. Front your instance with **load balancer**. This is the *easiest** way as you can associated ACM SSL certificate with the balancer for your domain.
2. Front your EB instance with **CloudFront (CF)**. You can setup alternative name for your cloudfront domain with your CF distro and your SSL cert. You can also use ACM for that. Also easy setup, but it should be noted that traffic between CF and your EB instance will be http only, unless you also setup your own SSL cert (not from ACM) on the instances (point 3).
3. Install your **own SSL certificate** (not from ACM) directly on the EB instance, using nginx. This requires manual setup and a valid public certificate. Popular choice is LetsEncrypt, to get the SSL cert from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My EB is using an Application load balancer, and I have followed the docs here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb/ I have used the Same (and only) SSL cert that my custom domain is using, and this has not fixed the problem. Does it perhaps need its own SSL cert?

Comment: @HaydenWilliams If you have SSL setup, then everything should go through your domain and https. You shoudn't make any calls in your app using http or eb domain. Also make sure that the ssl is correctly registered to your domain or its subdomains.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. I'm a new developer, so this problem arose from my confusion of API use cases and HTTPS. I was making api calls to my beanstalk url, which worked fine when testing and under HTTP. Calling my custom domain is clearly the right approach

Comment: Thanks for this post. How can I accomplish (3) above?

Comment: @Biiiiiird I would suggest making new question specific to your use case and issue.