# Issues in connecting AWS Cloudfront to app hosted on AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an app hosted on beanstalk environment(Blazor Server app), right now it is being served as:
Server(created by EBS) -> ALB(created by EBS) -> Route53(maps a CNAME record to the beanstalk domain).

I am planning to overcome the latency by introducing Cloudfront between the load balancer and route 53.

Since the load balancer is dynamically created by EBS, it doesn't seem reliable connecting Cloudfront to it as it may get replaced in the future.

Is there any way I can do what I am trying?
Can the beanstalk domain be used as an origin for Cloudfront? If yes, how? I haven't seen any documentation on it.

I have checked documentation but I couldn't find anything on this particular topic straightaway.

Comment: CloudFront allows any publicly-accessible URL as an origin. Add your Elastic Beanstalk domain as the origin domain in CloudFront (if using console, you can just paste it in)

Comment: @Cristian Seems like Beanstalk url doesnt have https enabled on it ( (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837847/how-to-enable-https-for-elastic-beanstalk-url) ). 
which gives me an error 502 when trying to point cloudfront distribution to it
Though I have ssl certificate attached to 443 listener on my alb, but that brings me back to square one, ie. the alb is spun off by Beanstalk and i can't point Cloudfront to the ALB.